# ruby-debug-ide version exception in Gemfile

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-debug-ide

Uncaught exception: You have already activated ruby-debug-ide 0.4.23, but your Gemfile requires ruby-debug-ide 0.4.22. Using bundle exec may solve this.

Comment: checkout https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-debug-ide/versions/0.4.23.beta11

Comment: Hello and Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was two version of ruby-debug-ide 0.4.23 and ruby-debug-ide 0.4.22.
we must have to uninstall one of them. just follow the processes:
1. gem list
2. gem uninstall ruby-debug-ide
3. select 1 or 2 (which one you want to uninstall)
4. bundle install

It will work in_sha_allah.